# Setup free TDS in php 7.1 and Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, database, php-7.1

I am having this issue on how to setup free tds on xampp with php 7.1 windows 10 x64. I am pretty new to working with Ms Sql servers what could be the sort out? Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sqlsrv driver instead. Freetds is not the way to go.
Try this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver
and
https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/4.1.6.1/windows

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostdb;dbname=$dbname", $usr, $psw);
```

becomes:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:host=$hostdb;dbname=$dbname", $usr, $psw);
```

Comment: I would rather use that, but the senior developer in my office said that they are using dblib in their existing projects. Using mssql would cause many queries to change? What would be the exact solution to deal with it. Cause I have been spinning my head through this all day. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only change off the top of my head, having only just upgraded myself. Is the connection string changes where it used to say dblib it will now say sqlsrv. 

UPDATED MY ANSWER.

The problem with dblib is that it has not been maintained for a long time while sqlsrv is actively supported by microsoft.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php